# Anyone got any plans to use Cryptol from Galois?

Tags: cryptography, dsl, cryptol

I saw in a Dr Dobb's email report for 2008-12-29 that there's a new DSL (domain-specific language) for designing crypto systems.  It is called [Cryptol](http://www.galois.com/technology/communications_security/cryptol) and is available from Galois.

Has anybody taken a look at it?  Does anyone have plans to use it?  Is it worthwhile, do you think?

---

Robert Gamble notes:

Cryptol is not new, it has been around for many years. What is new is the availability of (parts of) it to the public, it was originally developed for and used by the NSA.

---

Rather like Brian, I don't have any real reason to use Cryptol.  It might perhaps be useful if I needed to (re-)validate the SSL-based implementation we have, though I'm not sure it will help there (we don't need to validate the SSL library; we might need to validate our (mis-)use of the SSL library).

Comment: Cryptol is not new, it has been around for many years.  What is new is the availability of (parts of) it to the public, it was originally developed for and used by the NSA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because by modern standards, it is off-topic, though it was within the bounds of reason at the time it was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks interesting, but I don't currently have a good reason to use it myself.  Should be a benefit for other folks though.